# Question about general improvement path

Tags: discussion

<sup>See also the related question: [Wrote an answer while question got put on hold](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/651/wrote-an-answer-while-question-got-put-on-hold)</sup>

[This question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13770/i-wanna-be-a-badminton-player) asks about how to improve in a sport, namely Badminton in India. While the question is broad, I believe a good answer can be written, mentioning for example:

- the rough organization of the sport; including typical structure of associations/club/private training. This is often country-specific.
- a basic pathway in becoming a top athlete, again somewhat country-and most definitely sport-specific.
- Resources to start self-training
- equipment or other considerations

An answer can focus on one or more, but in any case a short description of the typical pathway to becoming a professional athlete would be sufficient to answer this type of question.

For these reasons, I would very much see [this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13770/i-wanna-be-a-badminton-player) reopened.

Comment: The question doesn't ask about how to improve in a sport...just states that the OP wants to play at a "higher level." That doesn't tell us anything specific. That said, this is an extension of the [how can I get started in a sport](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/474/are-questions-in-the-form-manner-how-can-i-get-started-in-sport-on-topic) question...and those questions are broad in nature.

Answer (score 4):

To me, the fact you need four bullet points to describe the *structure* of your answer pretty much determines that the question is too broad: the best answers probably have four bullet points in them in total :-)

Rather than trying to fix a broken question, perhaps the solution here is to ask a series of better questions, for example:

- How are badminton clubs organised in India?
- What is the route to becoming a national badminton player in India?
- What skills are the most important for a intermediate level badminton player to improve?
- What difference does better equipment make to a badminton player?

You may need to ask some or all of those questions yourself. That's not a problem as Stack Exchange [explicitly encourages self-answered questions](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: The question I get asked is `How do I become a better Badminton player?`, and this is one (India-focused) instance. Lots of the organizational stuff is completely irrelevant for an answer. Similarly, equipment or specific skills are not the point here, especially not equipment unrelated to training. I think that splitting it up into many small questions would miss the point, and make it practically impossible that somebody gets a coherent picture (unless there is a meta question or tag wiki connecting the various questions), even if they would manage to find the question.

Comment: I'm not keen on criticizing the answer, but agree with the list of "better questions." For these kind of questions, an answer that provides an outline is completely acceptable, and the bullet points provide that. From there, the OP can explore the bullet points, then ask more specific questions from there (thus, creating more useful content). These are similar to [how can I get started in a sport?](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/474/are-questions-in-the-form-manner-how-can-i-get-started-in-sport-on-topic) questions in which those are inherently broad.